# Android how to check whether the camera was used to take photo or video

Tags: android

I am using the following code to start device camera with both image and video mode swapping.So once i take a photo or video i am returned no value to identify whether the user took a photo or video.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_VIDEO_CAMERA);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Please help me with this

Comment: What do you mean with ` i am returned no value `? What are you getting in onActivityResult method?

Comment: when i take a photo or video its getting saved to the sd card but when it returns to my activity class the value for Intent is null, resultcode 0, requestcode 0. i am not passing any buddle for now. i am not familiar using this options

Comment: @Geoj If you use camera app, you won't receive the intent value. Intent value will be always null in this case. You have to get the recorded video or image from SDCard only. Intent data will be received when you use custom camera using surface view.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use both video and image mode from camera, please go through the following Site
This may help you with your requirement

[Camera With image and video capturing](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-working-with-camera-api/)

Preview

[image]

Comment: I want to use device camera so using MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA is the only option for me. Your suggestion is helpful when i customize my app camera. In my case it is not the option

Answer (score 0):

Override `onActivityResult` like the following

```java
onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    //this is how you check if a camera did take a picture
    if(resultCode== RESULT_OK && requestCode== 0) // in your case requestCode == 0
    {
        //here you get it
        Bitmap . bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras();
    }
}
```